# estou com problemas no codigo

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

gente eu estou fazendo um sistema escolar com python usando os modulos tkinter e SQLite mas quando eu insiro as variaveis das caixas de texto
nas informaçoes do banco de dados ele da esse problema

[image: ...]

deem uma olhada no meu script

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import sys
def bt1_click():
print('Nome do aluno: ',ed1.get())
print('Nome do responsavel: ',ed2.get())
print('Numero de contato: ',ed3.get())
print('Ano de escolariade: ',ed4.get())
print('data de naiscimento: ',ed5.get())
print('O aluno apresenta alguma deficiencia ?: ',texto.get("1.0",END))
root = Tk()
lb1= Label(text='nome do aluno: ')
lb2= Label(text='Nome do responsavel: ')
lb3= Label(text='Numero de contato: ')
lb4= Label(text='Ano de escolariade: ')
lb5= Label(text='data de naiscimento: ')
lb6= Label(text='Idade do aluno: ')
lb7= Label(text='O aluno apresenta alguma deficiencia ?: ')
lb8= Label(text='')

lb1.grid(row=1, column=0)
lb2.grid(row=3, column=0)
lb3.grid(row=5, column=0)
lb4.grid(row=7, column=0)
lb5.grid(row=10, column=0)
lb6.grid(row=9, column=0)
lb7.grid(row=11, column=0)
lb8.grid(row=13,column=0)

ed1= Entry('')
ed2= Entry('')
ed3= Entry('')
ed4= Entry('')
ed5= Entry('')
ed6= Entry('')
texto = Text('', height = 13, width = 20)

ed1.grid(row=2,column=0)
ed2.grid(row=4,column=0)
ed3.grid(row=6,column=0)
ed4.grid(row=8,column=0)
ed5.grid(row=10,column=0)
texto.grid(row=12,column=0)

bt1 = Button(text='enviar ao banco de dados', command=bt1_click)



bt1.grid(row=14,column=0)


root.geometry('220x500+100+100')

root.title('Ssystem')

root.mainloop()

ee1 = ed1.get()
ee2 = ed2.get()
ee3 = ed3.get()
ee4 = ed4.get()
ee5 = ed5.get()
ee6 = ed6.get()


banco = sqlite3.connect('SchoolSystem_Users.db')#objeto de conexao com o banco

cursor = banco.cursor()

#cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE users (Nome do aluno, Nome do responsavel, numero do responsavel,ano de escolaridade,data de naiscimento,idade do aluno)")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('ee1''ee2''ee3''ee4''ee5''ee5')")

banco.commit()

""" cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM users ''')
print(cursor.fetchall()) """

----------


==========
```

Comment: Conseuge conferir a identação do código que vocẽ colou? Está errada, e aí não podemos saber o que é parte de uma função e o que não é. 

Também, se tem mais de um arquibvo, ponha em blocos separados - você tem símbolos estranhos aí que seriam erro de sintaxe em Python (fileira de `-----` e de `====`) -  e por fim, seu código de banco de dados nessa listagem nunca vai rodar, já que está depois da chamada ao "mainloop". Ponha por ffavor uma listagem que funcione, e dê o erro que você quer esclarecer.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro se dá porque você tentou obter o conteúdo de uma variável após ela ter sido destruída, o `mainloop()` serve para fazer o programa rodar em loop, se você adicionar alguma instrução depois do `mainloop()` Ex.: `print('Olá')` isso só vai ocorrer após o usuário fechar o programa, e **depois que o programa for fechado a janela pai (nesse caso o root) deixa de existir, assim como todas as outras que foram definidas como filhas dela, Entradas, Botões, Widgets, etc.**

Também há 2 problemas simples no seu código:

1. Você esqueceu de identar a função `bt1_click()`
2. Você inseriu os caracteres `----------` e `==========` ao final da linha, o python irá gerar uma mensagem de  erro, porque ele não reconhece esses caracteres, você pode colocá-los como comentários.

Seu código da maneira correta ficaria assim:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import sys

def bt1_click():
    # Definindo as variáveis como sendo globais
    # Ou seja, elas poderão ser acessadas mesmo após a função bt1_click ser finalizada
    global ee1
    global ee2
    global ee3
    global ee4
    global ee5
    global ee6

    ee1 = ed1.get()
    ee2 = ed2.get()
    ee3 = ed3.get()
    ee4 = ed4.get()
    ee5 = ed5.get()
    ee6 = ed6.get()

    print('Nome do aluno: ', ee1)
    print('Nome do responsavel: ', ee2)
    print('Numero de contato: ', ee3)
    print('Ano de escolariade: ', ee4)
    print('data de naiscimento: ', ee5)
    print('O aluno apresenta alguma deficiência ?: ',texto.get("1.0",END))



root = Tk()
lb1 = Label(text = 'Nome do aluno: ')
lb2 = Label(text = 'Nome do responsavel: ')
lb3 = Label(text = 'Numero de contato: ')
lb4 = Label(text = 'Ano de escolariade: ')
lb5 = Label(text = 'data de naiscimento: ')
lb6 = Label(text = 'Idade do aluno: ')
lb7 = Label(text = 'O aluno apresenta alguma deficiencia ?: ')
lb8 = Label(text = '')

lb1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
lb2.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
lb3.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
lb4.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
lb5.grid(row = 10, column = 0)
lb6.grid(row = 9, column = 0)
lb7.grid(row = 11, column = 0)
lb8.grid(row = 13, column = 0)

ed1 = Entry('')
ed2 = Entry('')
ed3 = Entry('')
ed4 = Entry('')
ed5 = Entry('')
ed6 = Entry('')
texto = Text('', height = 13, width = 20)

ed1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
ed2.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
ed3.grid(row = 6, column = 0)
ed4.grid(row = 8, column = 0)
ed5.grid(row = 10, column = 0)
texto.grid(row = 12, column = 0)

bt1 = Button(text = 'enviar ao banco de dados', command = bt1_click)
bt1.grid(row = 14,column = 0)

root.geometry('220x500+100+100')
root.title('Ssystem')
root.mainloop()

# Printando todas as variáveis com os valores para garantir que esteja funcionando

print(ee1)
print(ee1)
print(ee2)
print(ee3)
print(ee4)
print(ee5)

banco = sqlite3.connect('SchoolSystem_Users.db')#objeto de conexao com o banco

cursor = banco.cursor()

#cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE users (Nome do aluno, Nome do responsavel, numero do responsavel,ano de escolaridade,data de naiscimento,idade do aluno)")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('ee1''ee2''ee3''ee4''ee5''ee5')")

banco.commit()

""" cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM users ''')
print(cursor.fetchall()) """
```